# How to build a Python crawler for websites using oauth2

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0, web-crawler, foursquare

I'm new in web programming. I want to build a crawler for crawling the social graph in Foursquare by Python. 
I've got a "manually" controlled crawler by using the `apiv2` library. The main method is like:

```
def main():
    CODE = "******"
    url = "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?client_id=****&response_type=code&redirect_uri=****"
    key = "***"
    secret = "****"
    re_uri = "***"

    auth = apiv2.FSAuthenticator(key, secret, re_uri)
    auth.set_token(code)    
    finder = apiv2.UserFinder(auth)        

    #DO SOME REQUIRES By USING THE FINDER
    finder.finde(ANY_USER_ID).mayorships()
    bla bla bla
```

The problem is that at present, I have to type the URL in my browser and pick up the CODE from the redirect URL, and then update the CODE in my program, and run it again. I think there might be some way that I can code the CODE taking progress into my current program and make it automatic.

Any instruction or sample code is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You should check out the [python-oauth2](https://github.com/dgouldin/python-oauth2) module.  It seems to be the most stable thing out there.

In particular, [this blog post](http://pkarl.com/articles/connect-foursquare-api-oauth-python/) has a really good run down on how to do Oauth easily with Python.  The example code uses the Foursquare API, so I would check that out first.

I recently had to get oauth working with Dropbox, [and wrote this module](https://github.com/mvanveen/Dropblog/blob/master/oauth.py) containing the necessary steps to do oauth exchange.

For my system, the simplest thing I could think of was to `pickle` the Oauth client.  My blog package just deserialized the pickled client and requested endpoints with the following function:

```
get = lambda x: client.request(x, 'GET')[1]
```

Just makes sure your workers have this client object and you should be good to go :-)

Comment: Thank you for your attention, sir. I have a question that in the blog, it seems like the "code" is not required for taking the taken. Is that true? Cause in my library, the code is a required parameter to access token. I just update my code part. Hope to make the question more clear.

Comment: If I'm reading your code correctly, the `CODE` variable in your program is not needed; it's handled by Python-Oauth2.

Comment: I followed the steps in the blog you recommend, but got the 404 Not Found error while doing the client.request step. I checked the code, compared to the lib apiv2.py. I think this lib is actually for the oauth 1.0 not the oauth 2.0.

Comment: Sorry about that!  I used the blog post to derive my Dropbox implementation and had not tried it on Foursquare.  There are some promising directions mentioned in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481468/oauth2-python-provider).  Looks like there's a fork of python-oauth2 [here](https://github.com/dgouldin/python-oauth2) which **does** have oauth2 support.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do it every time. They'll give you a `token` that is good for X hours/day. Eventually you'll get 403 http code and you'll need to re-authenticate

Comment: I do get a token in the 'bla bla bla' part, something like autu.set_token(CODE) to get the authorization. But there is limitation for each token to request the server. I want to crawl users' relations and their venues. It seems cost a lot of requests that after crawling like 20 users, the token expires and I have to apply a new one. As the "code" is required for getting the token, I have to get the authorization by using my personal account. That's the part that I try to convert automatically. Or I wonder if there are other ways that can crawl the data without the "code" and token.