# use python to login a website with google oauth

Tags: python, web-crawler, google-authentication

We have a website which use google oauth for the authentication.

Basically, when you open this website, it will redirect you to the google login page. After login with google account, you then be redirected to website's homepage.

I want to develop a python crawler to fetch some information from the website. How can I login this google account automatically?

It can't be simply as `request.send('login?user=goole_account&password=google_password')` right?

Some howtos or code snippets are appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build a Python crawler for websites using oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038690/how-to-build-a-python-crawler-for-websites-using-oauth2)

Comment: All webs that that question give are dead... so... I think it can be answered here